# Owin Middleware results in 404 on server

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, owin

I have a owin middle ware it works on my IIS7 on my dev machine (win7).
But when deployed to a 2008 server the page returns 404

I hook up the middleware like this

```
public static class AppBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void InitTemplateStore(this IAppBuilder app, string templatePath, string fileMask)
    {
        TemplateStoreMiddleware.Init(templatePath, fileMask);
        app.Map("/templates", subApp => subApp.Use<TemplateStoreMiddleware>());
    }
}
```

The code that uses the middleware can be found here

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap.Demo

The site is hosted as an virtual app under the default web site on IIS

**edit:** Do I need to add any roles out of the default ones?

IIS is tring to use the StaticFile handler which offcourse is wrong, why is this happening?

```
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070002
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/knockout.bootstrap.demo/templates?root=shared
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\knockout.bootstrap.demo\templates
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
```

Comment: I have a similar issue with StaticFiles OWIN module: https://gist.github.com/koistya/9951731

Answer (score 10):

A few common reasons for a OWIN middleware not working as expected in IIS integrated pipeline.

1. Check if you have Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb nuget package installed in your project and its in the bin folder of your app.
2. Is your app pool a v4.0 Integrated mode one (most probably this one?)

[This](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline) article can be of help. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058873/how-to-get-iis-to-recognize-owin-startup-class) question I believe is similar to yours.

Comment: Both are correct, will check the links. It works out of the box on my win7 IIS7 with default settings (I create a app that points to the publish folder), this is very strange

Comment: I've verified that the Owin startup is firing, so my middleware is registered but still it does not work.

Comment: any fixes on this issue?

Comment: A user of my lib reported that he got the same problem and that this helped app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler); I will investigate why

Comment: Omg you saved my day too